# Linq to SQL The best Overloaded method Match error

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

How Come this is not allowed?

```
public void addInsertedInformationToDb() { 

            using(DbClassesDataContext myDb = new DbClassesDataContext(dbPath)){

                myDb.PatientInfos.InsertOnSubmit(insertPersonalInformation);
            }
        }
```

Where my insertPersonalInformation

```
 private PatientInfo insertPersonalInformation()
        {

            DbClassesDataContext myDb = new DbClassesDataContext(dbPath);

            PatientInfo patientInfo = new PatientInfo();

            patientInfo.Phy_ID = physcianID;
            patientInfo.Pat_First_Name = txtFirstName.Text;
            patientInfo.Pat_Middle_Name = txtMiddleName.Text;
            patientInfo.Pat_Last_Name = txtLastName.Text;
            patientInfo.Pat_Gender = cmbGender.Text;
            patientInfo.Pat_Marital_Status = cmbMaritalStatus.Text;
            patientInfo.Pat_Date_Of_Birth = dtpDOB.Value;
            patientInfo.Pat_Home_Add = txtHomeAdd.Text;
            patientInfo.Pat_Home_Num = txtPhone.Text;
            patientInfo.Pat_Work_Add = txtWorkAdd.Text;
            patientInfo.Pat_Work_Num = txtWorkPhone.Text;
            patientInfo.Pat_Prim_Physician = txtPrimPhysician.Text;
            patientInfo.Pat_Ref_Physician = txtRefePhysician.Text;

            return patientInfo;
        }
```

I kept on getting these errors

> Error  1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Linq.Table.InsertOnSubmit(PatientAdministration.PatientInfo)' has some invalid arguments   C:\Users\John\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\PatientAdministration\PatientAdministration\Pat_Demog.cs    101 17  PatientAdministration
>
> Error  2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'PatientAdministration.PatientInfo'   C:\Users\John\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\PatientAdministration\PatientAdministration\Pat_Demog.cs    101 50  PatientAdministration

What is the fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in [InsertOnSubmit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763516.aspx) you can just use entity object or valid expressions not calling arbitrary methods, linq2entity can't convert your method to required expression, You can do as below to come up with your problem:

```
       using(DbClassesDataContext myDb = new DbClassesDataContext(dbPath)){
            var patientInfo = insertPersonalInformation();
            myDb.PatientInfos.InsertOnSubmit(patientInfo);
        }
```

See [Insert with linq2entity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882643.aspx):

> To execute a SQL Insert, just add objects to the object model you have
>   created, and call SubmitChanges on the DataContext.

Finally don't forgot to call `myDb.SubmitChanges()`.

Comment: @user962206 is same as insert. See Updating part of referenced link, you should be more care in update (In fact you should first fetch entity then apply change on it).

Comment: but I am using a form. the link you are showing only shows a certain part what If I want to select multiple parts ?

Comment: @user962206, currently I'm using linq2nhibernate, I'm not update for linq2entity, but as I can remember It was really hard to update multiple records, and I used to stored procedures for this (when I was using linq2entity). I think you can ask this in new question. (How to update multiple record in one query by linq2entity). But I don't think they improve it.

Comment: Also you can use DataTable (but I prefer stored procedures).

Comment: Any links with that? DataTable or Storeprocedures? for updating?

Comment: @user962206, I think This [Code Project article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/53669/Bulk-INSERT-UPDATE-DELETE-in-LINQ-to-SQL) is good.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8496/discussion-between-saeed-amiri-and-user962206)

Answer (score 0):

Your code works just fine just call the method like this:

```
myDb.PatientInfos.InsertOnSubmit(insertPersonalInformation());
myDb.SubmitChanges()
```

You forgot to add the parentheses.